# rewrite rules and querystring

Tags: url-rewriting, regex, query-string

When I go to the url `mysite.com/photos/120` I'm *wanting* to get the `120` out.

In the PHP I want to be able to grab these "parameters" like the url was `mysite.com?page=photos&id=120` or even just `mysite.com/photos?id=120`

Can I leverage **rewrite rules**? Or do I need to do **regex** in php to get what I want?

**** EDIT 1 ****

For the life of me I can't get this to work. Based on the answers given here is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_photo_url' );
function rewrite_photo_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^photos/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page=photos&photo_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_rewrite_tag('%id%','([0-9]+)');

print(get_query_var('photo_id'));
```

I suspect I'm missing a concept somewhere?

**** EDIT 2 ****

I'm starting to see that perhaps this needs to be in functions.php so I now have:

```
function rewrite_photo_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^photos/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page=photos&photo_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
function register_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'photo_id' );
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_photo_url');
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars', 1 );
```

Now I just need to know how to get my desired var in my page template. I've tried

```
print(get_query_var('photo_id'));
```

But that's not doing the trick.

Comment: The only thing worse than no answers is three good answers. #dilemma

Comment: You're mixing the answers... you use `photo_id` as your variable in the rewrite rule, but add `id` instead of `photo_id` with `add_rewrite_tag()`!

Comment: The `add_rewrite_tag` should probably be inside the `rewrite_photo_url` callback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of doing research on this, the answer was this simple:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['page']
```

wrap that in an `intval` and viola.

Answer (score 12):

You can add your own rewrite rule which will let you tweak the query via URL parameters:

```
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_photo_url' );
function rewrite_photo_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'photos/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?page=photos&photo_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

If you need to use a custom variable, i.e. 'photo_id', you have to register the variable so it will be recognized by the query:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars', 10, 1 );
// 1 is the arg number 
function register_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'photo_id' );
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: You don't want the caret in your rewrite rule up there. WordPress prefixes all rewrite rules with one for you; also, you might want to add a `$` at the end so WordPress can still add endpoint permalinks if necessary. Also, I'd change the asterisk to `+`, since that will only get a match if there really is a photo id present. Other than that, all solid code. :D

Comment: soo I think I finally figured out that this needs to be in my theme's functions.php -- well now I think everything is working, but I'm not sure how to retrieve my value on the actual photos.php. Should it just be `print(get_query_var('photo_id'));` anywhere on the page?

Comment: `print( get_query_var( 'photo_id' ) );` should work. Are you sure that your template is the one being used? A quick test of echo-ing some static text near the get_query_var() should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, your answer helped me a lot. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`add_rewrite_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) to register your custom query variable ('id' in question):

```
add_rewrite_tag('%id%','([0-9]+)');
```

(The regex tells it only to accepts digits). Then to create your rewrite rule you can use [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

(both of these should be hooked onto `init`).

```
add_rewrite_rule('^photos/([0-9]+)/?','index.php?p=1234&id=$matches[1]','top');
```

where 1234 is the ID of your 'photos' page. You will need to flush rewrite rules once after adding these (go to the Permalink settings page). Then as **@DanielBachhuber** says, you can use out `get_query_var( 'id' )` to get the ID.

**Note**, while the regex in the `add_rewrite_tag` means this will only accept digits - you should probably still sanitize with `intval` (in any case it may be a string representation of a digit).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the rules are being generated, you can use the [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function to get the value of the 'photo' query var. If it's done properly, 'photo' should be an available query var. You'll need to sanitize the value with intval() or similar of course.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys this is what worked for me:

```
    $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', strtok(get_pagenum_link( 1 ), '?') ) ) . 'page/%#%/'.rtrim(str_replace('%2F','',substr(get_pagenum_link( 1 ),strlen(strtok(get_pagenum_link( 1 ), '?')))),'/'), 'paged' ),
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);
```

The base value is what really works the magic. No need to make any changes to the base value. I was pointed in the right direction by reading this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simple-pagination-page2-and-_get-parameters

Comment: Please do not add duplicate content. It's enough to add your answer to one question. If you think both questions are the same, then please flag them for closing. Thank you.